# Creating list in R, when some of the list elements are not available

Tags: r

I want to create a list based on some of the elements, even if the elements are not available.

```
> group_vars <- list(hhrace,hhethn,hhsize,hhinc,hhage,hhcnty,hhkids,hhgeo)
```

here `hhrace` and `hhcnty` do not exist, but I want to create a list without those elements.

```
> group_vars <- list(hhrace,hhethn,hhsize,hhinc,hhage,hhcnty,hhkids,hhgeo)
  Error: object 'hhrace' not found
```

**Desired Output-**

```
> group_vars
  hhethn,hhsize,hhinc,hhage,hhkids,hhgeo
```

without the `hhrace` and the `hhcnty`.

Comment: Maybe `group_vars <- mget(ls(pattern = "^hh"))`.

Comment: thanks for the input, it picks all objects which has HH. looking for more specific results.

Comment: Hi @sarathgk if any of the questions below answers your query, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the `v`-sign next to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can store them in a list of expressions with `rlang::exprs` and only keep the ones which exist:

```
library(purrr)

# define variables in global environment
hhethn <- hhsize <- hhinc <- hhage <- hhkids <- hhgeo <- TRUE

group_vars <- rlang::exprs(hhrace, hhethn, hhsize, hhinc, hhage, hhcnty, hhkids, hhgeo) %>% 
  keep(~exists(as.character(.x))) %>% 
  set_names(as.character(.)) %>% 
  map(eval)

group_vars
#$hhethn
#[1] TRUE
#
#$hhsize
#[1] TRUE
#
#$hhinc
#[1] TRUE
#
#$hhage
#[1] TRUE
#
#$hhkids
#[1] TRUE
#
#$hhgeo
#[1] TRUE
```

For a more general case you can create a function:

```
safe_list <- function(...){
  rlang::enexprs(...) %>% 
    keep(~exists(as.character(.x))) %>%
    set_names(as.character(.)) %>% 
    map(eval)
}

group_vars <- safe_list(hhrace, hhethn, hhsize, hhinc, hhage, hhcnty, hhkids, hhgeo)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to pick up a solution suggested in the comments, which I believe is more useful than appreciated.

To set the stage, let's create the objects as DiceboyT has done:

```
hhethn <- hhsize <- hhinc <- hhage <- hhkids <- hhgeo <- TRUE
```

I am also creating a vector with the names of the existing objects:

```
objects <- c("hhrace","hhethn","hhsize","hhinc","hhage","hhcnty","hhkids","hhgeo")
```

Now, I may be wrong, but I have a hunch that all you need is the vector of objects that actually exist. The following would help with that:

```
objects[objects %in% ls()]
[1] "hhethn" "hhsize" "hhinc"  "hhage"  "hhkids" "hhgeo"
```

However, if you truly want to list, the following would help as well, setting all missing elements to FALSE:

```
mget(objects, ifnotfound = FALSE)
$hhrace
[1] FALSE
$hhethn
[1] TRUE
$hhsize
[1] TRUE
$hhinc
[1] TRUE
$hhage
[1] TRUE
$hhcnty
[1] FALSE
$hhkids
[1] TRUE
$hhgeo
[1] TRUE
```

Now, to get a list of these except for the missing ones, we could also do the following:

```
tmpfun <- function(lst, nme) {
  tryCatch(
    lst[[nme]] <- get(nme)
    , error = function(e) {return(lst)}
  )
  return(lst)
}

Reduce(tmpfun, objects, init = list())
$hhethn
[1] TRUE
$hhsize
[1] TRUE
$hhinc
[1] TRUE
$hhage
[1] TRUE
$hhkids
[1] TRUE
$hhgeo
[1] TRUE
```

which gives you the above results except for the cases where the object does not exist.

Comment: My went somewhere similar. I think you can improve on your `tmpfun` using built-in functions, `Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), mget(objects, ifnotfound = list(NULL)))`. The only thing left is to wrap it up in its own function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

**INPUT**-

```
> objects <- c("hhrace","hhethn","hhsize","hhinc","hhage","hhcnty","hhkids","hhgeo")
> hhsize=list(a=2)
> hhinc=list(a=5)
> hhethn=list(a=50)

> sapply(objects,function(x) if(exists(x)) TRUE else  FALSE)
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
hhrace hhethn hhsize  hhinc  hhage hhcnty hhkids  hhgeo 
 FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

**Note-** To get available `lists` in your `env` you can use below code-

To just get `list` names which are available in `env` you can use-

```
> names(which(sapply(objects,function(x) if(exists(x)) TRUE else  FALSE)))
[1] "hhethn" "hhsize" "hhinc"
```

To get complete list elements you can use below code

```
> mget(names(which(sapply(objects,function(x) if(exists(x)) TRUE else  FALSE))))

$hhethn
$hhethn$a
[1] 50


$hhsize
$hhsize$a
[1] 2


$hhinc
$hhinc$a
[1] 5
```